# Break out while loop and go to if/else

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop, break

I'm having problem to break out a while loop and start from the beginning of the while loop. I want to loop to check continuously if the time is equal to 59 seconds if not go to the while loop to check the logfile. The inner while loop should only do something when something specific is found in the logfile.

EDIT: New script. Problem is that the while loop doesn't run and don't go back to the function that calls the function again in the else  loop

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash    

counterSearch=0
counterIssue=0
counterPassed=0
counterFailed=0
counterSearchPassed=0
counterSearchFailed=0
counterIssuePassed=0
counterIssueFailed=0
counterTotal=0
counterHourly=0
counterAddHourly=0
declare -a hourlyScan=('6' '0' '5' '0' '7' '2' '0' '13' '0' '18' '0' '0' '7' '0' '6' '0' '0' '1' '3' '0' '0' '0' '3' '0')    

function readLogFile {    

tail -n0 $logJira | \
while read line ; do      

    if echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/search.*PASSED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Search and passed API action" >> $logIng
       counterSearch=$((counterSearch+1))
       counterPassed=$((counterPassed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Passed API Authentication: $counterPassed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total search API actions: $counterSearch" >> $logIng
       continue 2    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/search.*FAILED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Search and failed API action" >> $logIng
       counterSearch=$((counterSearch+1))
       counterFailed=$((counterFailed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Failed API Authentication: $counterFailed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total search API actions: $counterSearch" >> $logIng
       continue 2    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/issue.*PASSED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date - Issue and Passed API action" >> $logIng
       counterIssue=$((counterIssue+1))
       counterPassed=$((counterPassed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Passed API Authentication: $counterPassed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total issue API actions: $counterIssue" >> $logIng
       continue 2    

    elif echo "$line" | grep -e "/rest/api/2/issue.*FAILED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
       echo "$date -Issue and Failed API action" >> $logIng
       counterIssue=$((counterIssue+1))
       counterFailed=$((counterFailed+1))
       counterHourly=$((counterHourly+1))
       counterTotal=$((counterTotal+1))
       echo "$date - Total Failed API Authentication: $counterFailed" >> $logIng
       echo "$date - Total issue API actions: $counterIssue" >> $logIng
       continue 2
    fi
done
}    

function runner {
while true; do
currentMinute=$(date +%S)
currentHour=$(date +%k)
currentDay=$(date +%u)
currentWeek=$(date +%W)
  if [[ $currentMinute -eq 59 ]]; then
    if [[ ${#hourlyScan[@]} -eq 24 ]]; then
       unset hourlyScan[23]
       hourlyScan=($counterHourly "${hourlyScan[@]}")
       counterHourly=0    

       for i in "${!hourlyScan[@]}"; do
          $cliScript --server $cliServer --user $cliUser --password $cliPass --action modifyPage --space "VEN" --title "API Usage Monitoring" \
          --findReplaceRegex "<tr><td>$i</td><td>(\d*)</td></tr>:<tr><td>$i</td><td>${hourlyScan[$i]}</td></tr>"
       done
    fi
  else
    readLogFile
  fi
done
}    

runner
```

Comment: Can you come up with a shorter example that demonstrates the same problem? It's not clear how this differs from your previous question.

Comment: Wouldn't putting the second while loop as an else case to the "if -eq 59" work? What have you tried?

Comment: That doesn't work with the tail statement if i put it in the else statement. I tried two while loops in the outer while loop but that also didn't work..

Comment: I need something that breaks out the while loop but doesn't out the outer while loop and still checks if one of the statements is true i guess?

Comment: I did also tried it with functions. But that didn't helped sadly enough.

Comment: The problem is you pass the `-F` (or `--follow`) option to `tail`. That will cause your loop to keep attempting to read from the log file ignoring any time. Don't pass the `--follow` option, instead, you can just periodically call `tail` (and you can use `dd` to skip everything you have already printed) while continuing to keep an eye on the clock.

Comment: Hi David. I don't get it. You mean with the if else statement or something else? Thank you.

Comment: Every time you have a pipeline, such as `tail | while`, modification of variables are local to the sub-shell caused by the pipeline. Changes to counterHourly is not propagated to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Your tail display last 0 lines. So your `$line` is empty.

> tail -n0

You should remplace this zero value

**Examples**:

```
> tail -n20 file.txt #display last 20 lines of file.txt
```

-n, --lines=K   Output the last K lines, instead of the default of the last 10; alternatively, use "-n +K" to output lines starting with the Kth.

EDIT again : If you want to read the complete file, there my way to do it

```
while read line  
do   
   echo -e "$line\n"  
done < file.txt
```

Comment: I already added continue to the while loop that checks the logfile. But the if statement above is never executed.

Comment: The while loops keeps running, that is ok. But that if statement should also be running when the second is 59 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your last sentence. Anyway did you try to use  `tail -n0 $logJira` instead of  `tail -n0 -F $logJira` ?

Comment: Yes. See last code in begin post. What i mean is that one of the loops runs fine and the other one is skipped everytime..

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I've updated my answer. Can you check it. Regards.

Comment: You mean this:  tail -n10 +K $logJira ?

Comment: In 'tail -nX'    X is the number of lines that you want to display, I have edited again my answer to be more clear

Comment: If i ad a higher number instead of 0 it runs forever. So that doesn't work sadly enough.

Comment: A lot. The tail should do a live log scan. If a line occurs in that logfile and match the regex that it should do something.

Comment: When you say "If i ad a higher number instead of 0 it runs forever.", is that not normal ? You made an infinit loop... Can you be more precise when you say "it" runs for ever ? Anyway `tail -n0` is a mistake for me, make the test in terminal if you want. Try `tail -n0 your_file.txt` and `tail -n5 your_file.txt` if you want to test it.

Comment: Thank you. I got the while loop that scans the logfile working. So when something is found is executed that is in the if statement. The if loop that checks the time doesn't work. ( if [[ $currentMinute -eq 59 ]]; then if [[ ${#hourlyScan[@]} -eq 24 ]]; then) I need to break out the while loop that reads the logfile and execute the code in the if statement and than all over again. Got it haha?

Comment: I need to break out the while loop but keep the variables. The break out should go to the last function that does a if/else statement.

Comment: Yes you got it. But if your loop for check time doesn't work,  why don't you use `crontab` instead of ?

Comment: Problem is that we can't use crontab.. Yes i know it's really stupid haha

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a `break` in the inner loop. Imaging that my dummy example reflects what you want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
    echo done
    sleep
    count=0
    while true;
    do
    count=$(($count + 1))
    echo $count
    if [ $count == "100" ]; then
        break
    fi
    done
    continue
done
```

This will stop counting at 100 and go to the beginning of the first loop.

Comment: I tried it that way but it didn't work. Only the for loop get's executed sadly enough. Look at the begin post for the example.

Comment: Then I am pretty sure that the problem is somewhere else. But not because of the loop...